# midi - transferring sound output from the yamaha keyboard speakers into my own laptop (then headphones) in rosegarden

Tags: alsa, jack, midi, rosegarden

I have rosegarden and it works fine, i have sound recording notes in it but I want the output sound to play through my headphones via my computer instead of it playing through the keyboard in-built speakers. Is there a function where everything works exactly the same but can play straight into my headphones, muting it in my keyboard in built speakers? What is the feauture on rosegarden to change this?

Comment: I might try loading rosegarden, although I have only a passing interest in midi.  Are you running Jack for audio routing?

Comment: ok - how is it working for you?

Comment: My son uses Sibelius, I do mixing with a few different mixer makes.  It will be a day or two before I can get rosegarden running...

Comment: The reason I was asking about jack, is because if you have the pack to pulse bridge installed, you should be able to add routings to the pulseaudio in your computer, which then would play through the system speakers/headphone.

Comment: That's awesome - i am not quite sure how you would  do that. I do know that the qjackctl that i have installed is controlling and the keyboard makes no sound ( local is off) until rosegarden is opened and it starts making the noise through the keyboard's speakers.

Comment: do you know how you could divert the sound generated in rosegarden and transfer it to the PC's main speakers the pulse (audio) you were suggesting

Comment: use `sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-jack` to make the conneciton between Jack and Pulse.  You will probably need to restart, although there is a way of just causing it to load.  Jack can be,,,,,, tempermental

Comment: I have installed the pulseaudio-module-jack, and have included the command in the options of qjackctl that you need after startup- "pactl set-default-sink jack_out" but still  sound is coming out of the keyboard speakers

Comment: I was not able to run it in my vm last night, and I suspect I may need to have a midi device connected.